# Quoted JS object property names when evaled do not work as expected

Tags: javascript

Why does

```
eval('{pickup : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)}')
```

work and

```
eval('{"pickup" : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)}')
```

does not? I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

and yet

```
{"pickup" : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)}
```

as an object works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `{}` is interpreted as a block, not as an object literal, which makes `pickup` a [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), not an object key. This is what Javascript sees:

```
{
  pickup: 
    new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0);
}
```

If you want Javascript to see this as an object literal, assign it to something or otherwise make it an expression instead of a top-level statement.

Comment: [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533) because I tried to break it down too much XD

Comment: Never knew JS had a label statement

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the first one:

```
eval('{pickup : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)}')
```

Start parsing:

- `{` ... since we're not in a statement context that must be a **open block** bracket.
- `pickup:` is a **label**
- `new Date(...)` is a new date object, simple enough.
- `}` ends the code block.

So you see it's actually not doing anything close to what you expected :)

Now try the second one:

```
eval('{"pickup" : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)}')
```

Same thing:

- `{` is an **open block** bracket
- `"pickup"` is a string
- `:` is... unexpected. Syntax error!

To fix, force an expression context:

```
eval('({pickup : new Date(2012, 7, 23, 15, 49, 0, 0)})')
```

This will give you an object with a `pickup` property referencing the new date object.

Comment: Thanks for the great description.